# Jquery show alert on Div click only once

Tags: jquery, html, click

I have a div "AddRow" and on click on that div I am adding a row to table with Jquery.
Once I complete adding 5 rows and further clicking on div it shows alert "Rows Exceeded". How to show error only one time on clicking div again and again.

```
$('#AddRow').click(function () {
    //Check total rows 
    var maxNuber = 5;
    var rowCount = $('#tblTest tr').length;

    if (rowCount  < maxNuberOfFilters){
        AddRowToTable();
    }
    else{
        alert("Rows exceeded");
    }
});
```

Comment: Remove the click handler at that point?

Comment: @j08691 That runs under the assumption that Chandana wants the click handler to be removed upon exceeding the maximum rows. It appears to me that he only wants the *alert* to be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you

```
var rowCount = 1;
$('#AddRow').on('click','', function() {

    if (rowCount  <= 5){
        rowCount++; //replace with your logic and conditions...
    }
    else{
        alert("Rows exceeded");
        $('#AddRow').off('click');
    }
});
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/Hnuc7/

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var rowsExceeded = false;
$('#AddRow').click(function () {
    //Check total rows 
    var maxNuber = 5;
    var rowCount = $('#tblTest tr').length;

    if (rowCount  < maxNuberOfFilters){
        AddRowToTable();
    }
    else{
        if (!rowsExceeded) {
            alert("Rows exceeded");
            rowsExceeded = true;
        }
    }
});
```

I essentially just added a boolean variable that becomes true if rows are exceeded once. From then on, the variable will always be true, so the alert will never execute.

The benefit to this method is that the event handler is not unbound upon exceeding maximum rows.

Answer (score 1):

there is dozen of way doing this job but with respect to what you've down i can suggest this :

```
$('#AddRow').click(function () {
    //Check total rows 
    var maxNumber = 5;
    var rowCount = $('#tblTest tr').length;

    if (rowCount  < maxNumber){
        AddRowToTable();
    }
    else if(rowCount == maxNumber){
        alert("Rows exceeded");
        rowCount ++;
    }
});
```

Comment: That would result in an inaccurate rowCount. Say the user clicks on #AddRow 7 times. rowCount would then equal 7, but the actual number of rows would still be 5.